# Casual chess meet up in London UK

Tags: etiquette

I’m a (predominantly) online chess player.  My rating is roughly FIDE 1800-1900. I’m travelling to the UK next week for work.
Is there a place or club or cafe in the inner or outer London area where I can go and find like-minded strangers for a friendly casual game?

Answer (score 3):

I was in London two weeks ago, and attended a causal chess club in the central London.

http://casualchess.org/

It was a quiet pub, and the environment was good. What made it special was that it had a number of woman chess players. I tested my skills against those females.

As a FIDE 1800-1900 player, you will find yourself beating everybody there.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of clubs in London, googling "chess clubs in London" brings up Hammersmith, Battersea, Greater London, Metropolitan and Hackney for starters.

I don't play in London myself, save for tournaments, but I have heard of the last one (Hackney) and looking at their web page they do seem to have quite a lot going on:

http://hackneychess.org.uk/

Comment: Try [Battersea Chess Club London](https://www.batterseachessclub.org.uk/) too

Comment: "the oldest continually-existing chess club in London. " sounds like a good bet

Answer (score 1):

120 years ago *the* place to go and play chess in London was Simpsons in the Strand where you could drink, play and eat. Today that honour belongs to the Plough pub next to the British Museum which is where the Drunken Knights chess club play.

Their facebook page is [here](https://www.facebook.com/drunkenknights/).

Their London League details are [here](http://www.londonchess.org.uk/club.php?clubcode=4074).

Note that during the World Championships Simon Williams, the ginger GM, will be doing commentary from here. There will also be blitz and other events. More details [here](https://chessfestival.co.uk/).

Comment: looks like an amazing club to join!  If only I lived in London still

Answer (score 1):

just posted: blog article answering this very question

https://www.chessable.com/blog/2018/10/05/play-chess-in-london/